# Aurelia router-view inside dialog not working on reopening dialog

Tags: aurelia

As per example given in aurelia documentation I am opening dialog box with viewmodel (say prompt ). This prompt has view inside in which I am adding "router-view" tag.

My routes are already configured. So when first time I open dialog it opens correct views as configured in routes and everything works well. But when I close dialog and re-opens dialog, It's not showing first route view. If I click other route link and come back to first route it works.

I have observed it's not creating instance of view model of first route( when opened dialog second time). 
How to fix this issue?
Prompt html

```
<template><div class="row">
    <left-menu ></left-menu>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div></template>
<template>
```

and left-menu.htm

```
<template>
<div class="list-group">
    <template repeat.for="item of items">
        <a class="list-group-item ${$parent.selectedNav === item.routeName ? 'active' : ''}" route-href="route.bind: item.routeName;" click.delegate="$parent.select(item)">${item.text}</a>
    </template>        
</div>
```

Comment: I agree with 4imble below. The UX idea behind a router is a landing page, a place that you'd want someone to be able to navigate to and from. The UX idea behind a modal is a break in the page, some process that needs to take place in order for the logic on the page to complete or continue.

What you're probably building is a wizard, a multi-step modal dialog. To achieve this, I encourage using `<compose>` and managing the steps.

Answer (score 1):

Using a router inside a modal window seems off to me. The router is used to manage pages, but a modal is used to manage content within a page.

I would suggest building a modal window component, you can use `<slot>` tags to inject content and set it's model bindings to any data within the current view model.

Here's an example of my component that I use for this.

```
<template>
  <div show.bind="visibility" class="modal-window">
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm close-button" click.delegate="close()">close</button>
    </div>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
  <div show.bind="visibility" class="modal-window-overlay" click.delegate="close()"></div>
</template>
```

-

```
import { bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class ModalContent {
    @bindable visibility: boolean;

    close(){
        this.visibility = false;
    }
}
```

```
<modal-content id.bind="'add-variant-window'">
        <h4>Modal Content</h4>
        <div>you can bind this to things on the current viewmodel</div>
</modal-content>
```